# Problems with SVM to gender recognition

Tags: python

i've been working this days in a gender recognition project (in python) using  SVM but im lost with the result that i've obtained:

Why the recall Of Males are 0.09 and females 1? or the precision only 50% on Females?

```
SVM Accuracy: 0.540041067762
Classification report:
           precision   recall  f1-score   support
Females       0.52      1.00      0.68       242
Males         1.00      0.09      0.16       245

avg / total       0.76      0.54      0.42       487
```

I have all the images cropped, aligned and in grayscale
How can i improve the precision?

I need to change the Parameters of the: clf = svm.SVC() ?

My code:

```
import os, sys
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as Image
import cv2
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


def read_images(path, id, sz=None):
    c = id
    X,y = [], []
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            subject_path = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
            for filename in os.listdir(subject_path):
                try:
                    im = Image.open(os.path.join(subject_path, filename))
                    im = im.convert("L")
                    # resize to given size (if given)
                    if (sz is not None):
                        im = im.resize(sz, Image.ANTIALIAS)
                    X.append(np.asarray(im, dtype=np.uint8).ravel())
                    y.append(c)
                except IOError as e:
                    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
                except:
                    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
                    raise
                        #c = c+1

    return [X,y]


def main():

    contador = 0;

    # check arguments
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "USAGE: example.py </path/to/images/males> </path/to/images/females>"
        sys.exit()

    # read images and put them into Vectors and id's
    [X,x] = read_images(sys.argv[1], 1)
    [Y, y] = read_images(sys.argv[2], -1)

    # R all images and r all id's
    [R, r] = [X+Y, x+y]
    R_train, R_test, r_train, r_test = train_test_split(R, r)

    # Default svm
    clf = svm.SVC()   

    clf.fit(R_train, r_train)

    r_pred = clf.predict(R_test)

    target_names = ['Female', 'Male']
    print "SVM Accuracy:", accuracy_score(r_test, r_pred)
    print "Classification report:\n", classification_report(r_test, r_pred, target_names=target_names) 




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'd appreciate any kind of help in how can i make a good gender recognition with SVM Thanks for reading

ok, now with normalized data( Between 0 and 1 ) i try to use GridSearchCV to adjust C and Gamma using this:

```
    param_grid = [
  {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['linear']},
  {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'kernel': ['rbf']},
 ]
svr = svm.SVC()
clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(svr, param_grid)
```

after a while i get this results:

```
{'n_jobs': 1, 'verbose': 0, 'estimator__gamma': 0.0, 'estimator__probability': False, 'param_grid': [{'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}, {'kernel': ['rbf'], 'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001]}], 'cv': None, 'scoring': None, 'estimator__cache_size': 200, 'estimator__verbose': False, 'pre_dispatch': '2*n_jobs', 'estimator__kernel': 'rbf', 'fit_params': {}, 'estimator__max_iter': -1, 'refit': True, 'iid': True, 'estimator__shrinking': True, 'score_func': None, 'estimator__degree': 3, 'estimator__class_weight': None, 'loss_func': None, 'estimator__random_state': None, 'estimator': SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False), 'estimator__coef0': 0.0, 'error_score': 'raise', 'estimator__tol': 0.001, 'estimator__C': 1.0}

SVM Accuracy: 0.767326732673
Classification report:
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

    Females       0.76      0.77      0.76       294
    Males         0.78      0.77      0.77       312

avg / total       0.77      0.77      0.77       606
```

I do not know if it's the right way to use it, and what are the parameters C and gamma that give this result, but the classifier has improved, could someone tell me if I have done well and what the results mean or how can i do this? thanks

Comment: Since you asked for libraries which would be better suited for this task: any solid deep neural network library with support for convolutional nets and GPU support (assuming you have a decent GPU) should work ok. Look at Caffe, Torch7, keras... (the last one is in Python, if you prefer that). All of these have examples for training a deep net for image classification (usually ImageNet or CIFAR-10).

Comment: Thank you, then I will use keras so continue with python , I am currently working with a MacbookPro With Iris 1536 MB Intel GPU, will it be enough? This week I will work even with SVM changing some parameters and then I try to ' keras ' . thanks a lot @cfh

Comment: Also check out lasagne.

Comment: Btw, you should grid-search gamma and C and rescale your features. If they are grey-scale between 0 and 255 I would recommend dividing by 255.0 (make sure to get actual floating point numbers).

Comment: noted @AndreasMueller :)

Comment: Yeah, this week i'll work in that @AndreasMueller , why its better dividing by 255.0 ? To only have values between 0 and 1? How could i make that? Thanks

Comment: Yes, scaling to between 0 and 1 is usually a good idea. It will make the default parameters work better, too. But you should still use GridSearchCV to adjust C and gamma. How many samples do you have by the way?

Comment: Yeah, i need to read this http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html to adjust C and gamma, and i'll scaling the images too. I have 1200 images (aling) for each sample , but i can get more if necessary @AndreasMueller

Comment: Hi , I used GridSearchCV but I do not know if I did it well , you could look at my main question to see the results I obtained and see if I did right or wrong or what could be done better ? thanks @AndreasMueller

Comment: You should check what "clf.best_params_" is, and possibly extend your grid. Have a look at the second plot in http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html for a visualization for the grid search results.

Comment: Ok @AndreasMueller , i'll work in that, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table

```
SVM Accuracy: 0.540041067762
Classification report:
           precision   recall  f1-score   support
Females       0.52      1.00      0.68       242
Males         1.00      0.09      0.16       245
```

clearly indicates that your classifier identifies almost all examples as being female. Why is that? 100% recall means that all female samples have been correctly identified as female, whereas 100% precision for the male samples means that each sample that your classifier considered male was indeed male. On the other hand, 50% precision for the female population means that on average only half of the samples you classified as female were really female, while the other half were male.

If you think about it a bit, there can only be one conclusion: your classifier predicts a "female" label for (almost) whatever it is shown. Now you have to find out why that happens.

Comment: Ok, thanks @cfh i'll try with different crop, different size and maybe EqualizeHist the images, the parameters of the: 'clf = svm.SVC()'  could change anything?

Comment: One question @cfh , which means the column 'suppor', because the number of training data are 487 too (242+245), and how I can know the number of support vectors that are in the SVM model that I create? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be converting the pixels of each image into an array of numbers, and just hoping that SVM will somehow be able to distinguish sequences of female pixels from sequences of male pixels.

This "black magic" approach to classification is unlikely to succeed. Some sort of actual analysis of the images would seem like a more promising approach -- maybe try to quantify facial features, or even just the number of colors or edges. But this is not a simple hobby project where you can successfully approximate the state of the art over a weekend with simple off-the-shelf tools

Comment: Deep convolutional nets actually do work in this "black box" way (or black magic as you call it), so the OP can be excused for attempting this.

Comment: Also, with freely available libraries, this is a simple hobby project and can easily be done in a weekend, assuming you have a decently powerful GPU.

Comment: @cfh Right, but there is no neural network here, just the grey level of the pixel at a particular coordinate as a "feature". Do you expect "male" if (177, 413) is particularly dark? Of course you don't, and adding more pixels to look at doesn't really change that.

Comment: @cfh Agree that you could probably get acceptable results with a different approach, without a lot of effort, even; but "acceptable" is not very close to 100% for this type of problem.

Comment: A simple nearest neighbor algorithm, literally just computing which image is closest in Euclidean norm to a given image, can achieve over 97% accuracy on handwritten digit recognition [(source)](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). Would you expect a five if pixel (12,17) is black? And yet it works. And the results with CNNs are not "acceptable", they are state of the art, without any feature engineering. [Read up a bit](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/imagenet.pdf) if you are interested.

Comment: Digit recognition is a significantly different problem from gender identification. Absent prominent facial hair and/or cultural markers (makeup etc), even humans have a high error rate, and moreover often fail to  provide any reliable and actionable articulation of how they attempt to solve it.

Comment: Sorry, but now you're just backpedaling. How can you say how well the approach will work if you haven't tried it? Yes, it's a more difficult problem, and nobody expects 100% accuracy (don't know where you got that strawman from), but it's interesting to try and see how well it works. I am completely convinced that performance will be better than the 50% random guess accuracy that OP gets currently, and there must be a bug somewhere.

Comment: @cfh: Excuse me? The stuff about 100% is only saying that the accuracy will be disappointing if that is your expctation. Anyway, if you think the OP's approach -- which specifically requests a Support Vector Machine solution -- has any chance of working, in spite of evidence to the contrary, the onus of demonstrating that is on you. Maybe improving the feature model could help; but you seem in fact to be advocating a more radical departure from the OP's attempt

Comment: last week i tried Fisherfaces as Feature Extraction method and 1-NN classifier with Euclidean Distance and i though it was not enough reliable, so i try with SVM now, if u said that "exist freely available libraries, this is a simple hobby project and can easily be done in a weekend" , so, what libraries i can use and what method should be better than SVM? Thanks both of u for helping me @cfh and tripleee

Comment: Maybe you want to try neural networks, as suggested by @cfh above, but no prediction for how well to expect them to work for this particular task.

Comment: @cfh:  deep nets aren't black boxes for the scientists who design them. An actual implementation is black box because neural network can't justify their choices, but the theoretical mechanism is well explained and totally reasonable when you study it. In this case here, I don't think a neural network will enhance the results, because they are hard to get working right when you don't know how it works (and even when you do, it's still hard). The OP should try to project the data onto another representation, for example using PCA or random forests so the classifier works on a non linear space.

Comment: @gaborous: Believe me, I'm pretty familiar with the state of the art in ANN research (and by the way, the mathematical theory behind deep learning is not well understood at all). The point is that nowadays you can download libraries which come with ready-built example architectures for ImageNet or CIFAR-10 classification. These will work very well for this problem with only very minor adjustments.

Comment: 77% using the most minimal work seems to contradict the "black box won't work", though I agree that with just using sklearn-theano you could get much better with similarly many lines of code and a pretrained neural net.